# How to display the highest 3 array element in descending order?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, sorting

If i have two arrays of 10, like,

```
    int [] array = {2,10,3,4,8,9,7,5,6,1};
    string [] arrayname = {"one",  "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"};
```

and i want to display the highest 3 number, which is " 10, 9, 8 " in desc order, but the result is to be the "arrayname", not "array". So in the rich-textbox, i'll see

two six five

So like, how do i code it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result = arrayname.Select((m, index) => new
            {
                key = array[index],
                value = m
            })
                .OrderByDescending(m => m.key)
                .Select(m => m.value)
                .Take(3);


   var textBoxValue = string.Join(" ", result);
```

Comment: Probably there is something wrong here also because I get "two, six, five"

Comment: @Steve which is the desired result ? `So in the rich-textbox, i'll see
two six five`. Or do you just mean I should remove the comma ?

Comment: No really confused now. You are printing the indexes of the three highest number in the arrayname and this could be right, but then what does it mean  _i want to display the highest 3 number, which is " 10, 9, 8 " in desc order_ ?

Comment: @Steve well, if you read the entire phrase, it's rather clear, no ? TAKE the 3 highest numbers in descending order from array, and SHOW the corresponding elements in arrayname...

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `Zip`

```
  int[] array = { 2, 10, 3, 4, 8, 9, 7, 5, 6, 1 };
    string[] arrayname = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" };

    var dictionary = array.Zip(arrayname, (k, v) => new { Key = k, Value = v })
                         .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

    var result=dictionary.OrderByDescending(m => m.Key)
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .Take(3);


    var textBoxValue = string.Join(" ", result);
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering, but since i don't really know `zip`, like what it does, imma use the other ans :)

Comment: @MarcellaTay:The Zip operator merges the corresponding elements of two sequences using a specified selector function.If you want to learn more about this check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx